# android.os.networkonmainthreadexception Http Request

Tags: android, xmlhttprequest

Hi I'm about to perform an HTTP request to add some data to a local data base using wampserver, so I've made a button andh within that button i will perform that action , but the problem is that i can't connect to the data base !!!

this is the message apperas on the toast **"android.os.networkonmainthreadexception"**

and this is my code ---> http://pastebin.com/TsQ7NbNm

```
                    ============================
```

I'm Newer to Android Programming so please Help me !

Answer (score 1):

You cannot make http request on your UI thread. Consider using AsyncTask or some other method of asynchronuos call.

Comment: if you're new to Android, you should read some things first.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

I hope this will make it clearer to you.

Answer (score 1):

Upto the API level-10 it is fine to make http request on UI thread. But from API-11, any task that takes long time to complete must be done on background task. The reason behind this is any task that takes 5 seconds or more on UI thread then ANR(Application Not Responding) i.e. force close happens. To do that we have create some background thread or simply make use of AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to post data on your server then you need to well design server for post data. recent my server configuration i post data by using this code and well performed.

```
Button send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send_sms);        
    send.setOnClickListener(this);

public void onClick(View v) 
 {
       switch (v.getId()) 
       {

       case R.id.send_sms:

               try {
                    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();  
                    String postURL = "http://10.0.2.2/folder/saver.php";
                    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(postURL); 
                        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cell", "+8801899999"));
                        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pin", "1234"));
                        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("msg", "hi!"));
                        UrlEncodedFormEntity ent = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params,HTTP.UTF_8);
                        post.setEntity(ent);
                        HttpResponse responsePOST = client.execute(post);  
                        HttpEntity resEntity = responsePOST.getEntity();  
                        if (resEntity != null) {
                            showAlert(EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));
                            //Log.i("RESPONSE",EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));
                        }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


           break;


       }
 }
```

Comment: i"ve tried your code no errors but it does not work for me this my code how it's look --> http://pastebin.com/9NgekWqm

Comment: where is the problem , please help on this I've done it on iPhone very simply but with android it seems to be more difficult  :(

Answer (score 0):

you can try this way.if your server has password then give it.

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("test");


$valeur1=$_REQUEST['valeur1'];
$valeur2=$_REQUEST['valeur2'];

$req=mysql_query("insert into testapp (valeur1,valeur2) values('$valeur1','$valeur2')");
if($req)
echo "ok";
else
echo "erreur";
;
?>
```